# How to solve this system of $2$ equations?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

Let consider the following system :

$\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
            (x-1)(x-2)(x-4) &\equiv 0 \pmod{9} \\
            (x-1)(x-2)(x-4) &\equiv 0 \pmod{25} \\
            \end{array}
             \right.$

We know that  $\pmod{9}$ the polynomials has at most $3$ solutions, same for $\pmod{25}$.

The fact is that we don't have $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z}$ which are not integral domains (they are not fiels indeed). We can consider $\mathbb{F}_{9}$ and $\mathbb{F}_{25}$ which are fields but this times we cannot apply the CRT.

What methods could be useful ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: One question, why `we cannot apply the CRT`? From that we can deduce $(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)\equiv0\pmod{9\times25}$, can't we?

Comment: @user202729 I mean that with the CRT we will obtain 9 systems  but as they are not fields we cannot apply the isomorphism

Comment: @user202729 You cannot apply Euclid's lemma, they are not integral domains for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
   (x-1)(x-2)(x-4) &\equiv 0 \pmod{9} \\
   (x-1)(x-2)(x-4) &\equiv 0 \pmod{25} \\
\end{align}

From the second equation, we know that one possibility is 
$$x = 25u+1$$ 
for some integer $u$. Substituting into the first, we get
\begin{align}
   (25u)(25u-1)(25u-3) &\equiv 0 \pmod{9}\\
   (7u)(7u-1)(7u-3) &\equiv 0 \pmod{9}\\
   4(7u)\,4(7u-1)\,4(7u-3) &\equiv 0 \pmod{9}\\
   u(u-4)(u-3) &\equiv 0 \pmod{9}\\
\hline   
   u &= 9v\\
   u &= 9v+4\\
   u &= 9v+3\\
\hline
   x &= 225v + 1 \\
   x &= 225v + 101 \\
   x &= 225v + 76 \\
\hline
   x &\equiv 1 \pmod{225}\\
   x &\equiv 76 \pmod{225} \\
   x &\equiv 101 \pmod{225} \\
\end{align}

etcetera

### Note

It's not hard to show that $(x-1)(x-2)(x-4) \equiv 0 \pmod{25} $ only has solutions $\{1,2,4\} \pmod{25}$.

Since $\mathbb Z_5$ is a field, the solutions to 
$(x-1)(x-2)(x-4) \equiv 0 \pmod{5} $
are $\{1,2,4\} \pmod{5}$

If you try $x = 5t+1$, you get

\begin{align}
   5t(5t-1)(5t-3) &\equiv 0 \pmod{25} \\
   t(5t-1)(5t-3) &\equiv 0 \pmod 5 \\
   t(-1)(-3) &\equiv 0 \pmod 5 \\
   3t &\equiv 0 \pmod 5 \\
   t &\equiv 0 \pmod 5
\end{align}

So $x \equiv 1 \pmod{25}$

The same will go for the other two roots.

## A SECOND SOLUTION

Let's start with $(x-1)(x-2)(x-4) \equiv 0 \pmod 9$ This implies, but is not equivalent to, the simpler equation $(x-1)(x-2)(x-4) \equiv 0 \pmod 3$. We can simplify this to $(x-1)^2(x-2) \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, and, because $\mathbb Z_3$ is a field, the solution set is $x \in \{1,2\} \pmod 3$.

If $x \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, Then $x = 3t+1$ for some integer $t$. Then

\begin{align}
   (x-1)(x-2)(x-4) &\equiv 0 \pmod 9 \\
   (3t)(3t-1)(3t-3) &\equiv 0 \pmod 9 \\
   9t(3t-1)(t-1) &\equiv 0 \pmod 9 \\
   0 &\equiv 0 \pmod 9
\end{align}

So $t \in \mathbb Z$. This implies that 
$x \in \{\dots, -5, -2, 1, 4, 7, \dots\}$, which simplifies to 
$x \in \{1, 4, 7\} \pmod 9$

If $x \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, Then $x = 3t+2$ for some integer $t$. Then

\begin{align}
   (x-1)(x-2)(x-4)  &\equiv 0 \pmod 9 \\
   (3t+1)(3t)(3t-2) &\equiv 0 \pmod 9 \\
   3t(3t+1)(3t-2)   &\equiv 0 \pmod 9 \\
   t(3t+1)(3t-2)    &\equiv 0 \pmod 3 \\
   t(1)(-2)         &\equiv 0 \pmod 3 \\
   -2t              &\equiv 0 \pmod 3 \\
   t                &\equiv 0 \pmod 3 \\
\end{align}

So $x \in \{\dots, -16, -7, 2, 11, 20, \dots\}$. This implies that $x \in \{2\} \pmod 9$.

Putting the two solutions together, we get $x \in \{1,2,4,7\} \pmod 9$.

So now we tackle $(x-1)(x-2)(x-4) \equiv 0 \pmod{25}$. Just as before, this implies that $(x-1)(x-2)(x-4) \equiv 0 \pmod 5$, which implies that 
$x \in \{1,2,4\} \pmod 5$.

If $x \equiv 1 \pmod 5$, Then $x = 5t+1$ for some integer $t$. Then

\begin{align}
   (x-1)(x-2)(x-4) &\equiv 0 \pmod{25} \\
   (5t)(5t-1)(5t-3) &\equiv 0 \pmod 5 \\
   t(5t-1)(5t-3) &\equiv 0 \pmod 5 \\
   3t &\equiv 0 \pmod 5 \\
   t \equiv 0 \pmod 5 \\
\end{align}

Which implies that $x \in \{1\} \pmod{25}$.

The other two cases are similar; so we can conclude that 
$x \in \{1,2,4\} \pmod{25}$.

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, $\bar a \in \mathbb Z_9$ is a solution to $(x-1)(x-2)(x-4) \equiv 0 \pmod 9$ and $\bar b \in \mathbb Z_{25}$ is a solution to $(x-1)(x-2)(x-4) \equiv 0 \pmod{25}$ if and only if $\bar c = 100 \bar a - 99 \bar b \in \mathbb Z_{225}$ is a solution to $(x-1)(x-2)(x-4) \equiv 0 \pmod{225}$.

We can make a table.

$\begin{array}{cc|c}
   a \pmod 9 & b\pmod{25} & 100a - 99b \pmod{225} \\
\hline
   1 & 1 & 1 \\
   2 & 1 & 101 \\
   4 & 1 & 76 \\
   7 & 1 & 151 \\
   1 & 2 & 127 \\
   2 & 2 & 2\\
   4 & 2 & 202 \\
   7 & 2 & 52 \\
   1 & 4 & 154 \\
   2 & 4 & 29 \\
   4 & 4 & 4 \\
   7 & 4 & 79 \\
\hline
\end{array}$

So the solution set is

$x \in \{1, 2, 4, 29, 52, 76, 79, 101, 127, 151, 154, 202\} \pmod{225}$

Comment: How can you say that $25 \mid (x-1)$ ?

Comment: @Maman No, $25|(x-1)$ is just one possibility. There are other possibilities ($25|x-i$ for $i$ from 0 to 24), and you have to solve them yourself.

Comment: @user202729   Ok indeed if $25$ divides all the $(x-i)$ then it divides the product and to be on a field is not necessary

Comment: @user202729 but here we affirm that $25\mid(x-1)$

Comment: It comes from the properties of $p^a=q$ ? Because the fact is that we cannot not say if $c$ (not prime) divides a product the $c$ divides one of the factors...

Comment: I still have the impression that you use Euclid's lemma. I'm confused...

Comment: @maman - I added one more line to my note. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm a bit confused in the sense where if I have $(x-1)...(x-n)\equiv 0 \pmod p$ I have the fact that $p$ must divide one of the $(x-i)$ (by Euclid or integral domain. However in the case :$(x-1)...(x-n)\equiv 0 \pmod {p^a}$ we cannot conclude that $p^a$ must divide one of the $(x-i)$...

Comment: It's strange because it seems that you consider $\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z}$ as an integral domain

Comment: @Maman - Please explain. The only structure I used was that $\mathbb Z_5$ is a field.

Comment: I mean that if you have $(x-1)...(x-n)\equiv 0 \pmod{p^a}$ you cannot say say $p^a \mid (x-1)$ for instance because $p^a$ is not prime (so no Euclid's lemma) and $\mathbb{Z}/p^a\mathbb{Z}$ is not an integral domain. In the case of the exercise we cannot say that if $(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)\equiv 0 \pmod{25}$ then $25\mid (x-1)$ or $(x-2)$ or $(x-4)$ because $\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z}$ is not an integral domain...

Comment: For example, with integers $4\mid 12=2\times 6$ but $4$ divides neither.

Comment: @Maman - I know what an integral domain is. Where do you think I did it?

Comment: In your answer you said that seeing the second equation $25 \mid (x-1)$ then we do the same for the two factors. But for me, you use a statement from integral domain. I don't understand. Here, we just can say that $25$ divides the product and if it divides every term of the form $(x-i)$ (but here we do not know that fact) then it can divide the product. It seems that the reverse is done... Look at $4\mid12=2\times6$.

Comment: Or maybe I think that your method work just if the polynomial has exactly the same roots $\pmod p$ and $\pmod{p^a}$. But is it always true ? It seems to work with roots whose multiplicity is $1$, I'm not sure ...

Comment: So I still don't know

Comment: Ok the second solution is clearer for me and it enables to deduces a nice result on the solutions $\pmod p$ and $\pmod{p^a}$. Thanks for  patience !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46226/discussion-between-steven-gregory-and-maman).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

As $9$ and $25$ are relative primes, the solution is of the form

$$(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)=3^25^2k$$

You can try and match all factorizations of the RHS in three increasing factors. You can even restrict to $oee$ and $eoo$ parities.